# how to set earliest date in latest date as a subject while sending a mail?

Tags: iphone, xcode, object

In my app i have use email functionality.In that i have to make report of all records of 
 database.In that i have to set subject as earliest date-latest date.and this date comes from 
 the database.i am using sqlite database and i have fields like Entrydate,Amount,LastEdited..

```
  how do i set the earliest date and latest date in subject?
```

here is code:

```
      [mailController setSubject:@"Bill Report"];
```

i have to set earliest date and latest date after the Bill Report

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First fetch data from SQLite database and then use as mailcomposer subject.